# PROBLEM: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". Builds and Runs Fine though

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, mapkit

i'm NEW TO XCODE, working with mapkit and annotations, howver after building and running fine,
the application crashes on load. I ran the debugger and;

Stopped at Breakpoint 1 'mapView:viewForAnnotation: - Line 951'

continues after a few hit counts,

Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

I've read countless solutions something to do with alloc or releasing or something but have no idea where the problem is in my code.

EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED.

Comment: If you let it run with the debugger attached (not only debug config), it will stop right away at the offending line. Would be helpful to know which line that is here (line 951?)

Comment: BTW, your code is horribly duplicated... putting everything in collections and using iteration will make writing and reading much easier. It's really worth it! :-)

Comment: MKUserLocation.class  should be [MKUserLocation class]

Comment: MainViewAnnotationView *annotationView = nil; is where it stops

Comment: and changing the MKUserlocation command causes an error

Comment: this code is interesting, you should learn a bit about how to use a plist to organize your data. I can see obviously that you can put this long if/else to a plist.

Comment: Is there an error message in your debugger console?

Comment: what is line 951? That is a breakpoint you set or the debugger stopped due to an exception there?

Comment: The line with "if ([annotation isKindOfClass:MKUserLocation.class]) return 0;" looks dodgy to me. First of at, it's better coding style to return nil instead of 0 for objects. And more importantly, this whole error seems to be ignored by you. You at least want to log this problem (NSLog) or show some notification to the user.

Comment: @Frank, that's not an error case. You're right that he should return nil rather than 0, but he's basically asking the MapView to take care of producing the blue user-location dot view for him.

Comment: @Jon, if you would add back the relevant code and explain what the issue was, you can help the rest of us answer similar questions that come up again in the future.

Comment: After going through lines of code the debugger couldn't show me that I had duplicated a line of code in my AnnotationView, the MapViewController was not the issue. But hey, thanks to you my code is a little cleaner ^^. Seamus, I would love some advice on searching a tableview of annotations. If i post a question, i'd love to hear your input.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594558/searching-a-tableview-of-annotations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but i highly recommend you use a switch statement to replace the long "else if" code. Makes your code look much cleaner and your compiler can do optimizations.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement

Edit;
After looking at the other comments (from Eiko), I have to agree that in this case you even want to remove this whole piece of code and replace it with some collection. The code contains too much duplications.

Comment: No, actually he should use a loop.

Comment: i have no idea where to begin, i'm very new have no idea what im looking at half the time. I'm trying to complete this for a uni project

Answer (score 3):

If there is a crash, there is a backtrace.  Post it.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously too much code to go through.

Here is how you can figure these errors.

a) Enable "Stop on Objective-C exceptions" in Run menu of XCode. This will get you pretty close to where the error occurred. Just look at the stack and you will be able to figure.

b) If that does not help, then try the NSZombie route although I have never had a need to use it. http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease . I mostly figure by just reviewing  the code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And also use the Debugger Shift-Cmd-Y (in Run menu) if you have not started using it yet.

Comment: what annoys me is i've had this working perfectly before but i decided to create some more annotations, add some annotation types and now it's come with this error. the error stops at - (MainViewAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation

Comment: We're advised to show as much code as poss now i've shown too much, great

Answer (score 1):

`mapView:viewForAnnotation` could be dramatically shorter, without using plists or collections. A reuse identifier is useful for dequeueing annotations of a particular type or annotations that perhaps have expensive-but-identical setup work.  You're initializing every one of your annotations the same way, so they can all use the same reuse identifier without issue. The function could thus be written:

```
- (MainViewAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{   
    if(annotation == mapView.userLocation) return nil;

    NSString* identifier = @"City";
    MainViewAnnotationView *newAnnotationView = (MainViewAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(nil == newAnnotationView)
    {
        newAnnotationView = [[[MainViewAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    }

    [newAnnotationView setEnabled:YES];
    [newAnnotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];

    return newAnnotationView;
}
```

Comment: very detailed example thank you very much, though i still getting my EXC BAD ACCESS error

Comment: I think you're going to have to read up a bit on using the debugger so you can give us more information on the error before we can help you any more.

Comment: -[MapViewController tableView:cellforRowAtIndexPath:]

its stops at CellIdentifier
and the annotation variables say they are out of scope?

On EXC_BAD_ACCESS error,
0x023dc668  <+0044>  movzbl (%esi,%ecx,1),%eax